# C# Handling DDD domain events with dynamically constructed event handlers

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, domain-driven-design, autofac

I am building an application using ASP.NET Core 2.0 with EF Core 2.0. As for decoupling different kind of logics in my domain, I use domain events of DDD (Domain Driven Design). Let's dive into the implementation and see what I have, then I will discuss my issue. 
First of all let's see the generic implementation of my domain-event-related classes. Firstly a marker interface, `IDomainEvent`:

```
public interface IDomainEvent
{
}
```

Next to it I have a generic `IHandler` class:

```
public interface IHandler<in T> where T : IDomainEvent
{
    void Handle(T domainEvent);
}
```

Then I have a `DomainEvents` class:

```
private static List<Type> _handlers;

public static void Init()
{
    InitHandlersFromAssembly();
}

private static void InitHandlersFromAssembly()
{
    _handlers = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
        .GetTypes()
        .Where(x => x.GetInterfaces().Any(y => y.IsGenericType && y.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IHandler<>)))
        .ToList();
}

public static void Dispatch(IDomainEvent domainEvent)
{
    foreach (var handlerType in _handlers)
    {
        if (CanHandleEvent(handlerType, domainEvent))
        {
            dynamic handler = Activator.CreateInstance(handlerType);
            handler.Handle((dynamic)domainEvent);
        }
    }
}

private static bool CanHandleEvent(Type handlerType, IDomainEvent domainEvent)
{
    return handlerType.GetInterfaces()
        .Any(x => x.IsGenericType
                  && x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IHandler<>)
                  && x.GenericTypeArguments[0] == domainEvent.GetType());
}
```

As you can see the `DomainEvents` class initializes all the domain events of the executing assembly. The `Dispatch` method is called in an overrided `SaveChanges()` method of my custom `DbContext` of the domain. I call the dispatch here in order to dispatch the all events at the of the transaction of an unit of work:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    DomainEventsDispatcher.Dispatch(ChangeTracker);

    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

And the implementation of `DomainEventDispatcher`:

```
public static class DomainEventsDispatcher
{
    public static void Dispatch(ChangeTracker changeTracker)
    {
        var domainEvents = GetDomainEventEntities(changeTracker);

        HandleDomainEvents(domainEvents);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<IEntity> GetDomainEventEntities(ChangeTracker changeTracker)
    {
        return changeTracker.Entries<IEntity>()
            .Select(po => po.Entity)
            .Where(po => po.Events.Any())
            .ToArray();
    }

    private static void HandleDomainEvents(IEnumerable<IEntity> domainEventEntities)
    {
        foreach (var entity in domainEventEntities)
        {
            var events = entity.Events.ToArray();
            entity.Events.Clear();

            DispatchDomainEvents(events);
        }
    }

    private static void DispatchDomainEvents(IDomainEvent[] events)
    {
        foreach (var domainEvent in events)
        {
            DomainEvents.Dispatch(domainEvent);
        }
    }
```

So far so good, it works pretty well with simple domain event handlers, for example:

```
public class OrderCreatedEventHandler : IHandler<OrderCreatedEvent>
{
    public void Handle(OrderCreatedEvent domainEvent)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Order is created!");
    }
}
```

But I have some other event handlers where I would like to inject some dependency, namely a Repository:

```
public class OrderCreatedEventHandler : IHandler<OrderCreatedEvent>
{
    private readonly IOrderHistoryRepository _orderHistoryRepository;

    public OrderCreatedEventHandler(IOrderHistoryRepository orderHistoryRepository)
    {
        _orderHistoryRepository = orderHistoryRepository;
    }

    public void Handle(OrderCreatedEvent domainEvent)
    {
        _orderHistoryRepository.Insert(new OrderHistoryLine(domainEvent));
    }
}
```

My issue is the following: In `DomainEvents` class `Dispatch` method I use `Activator` class to dynamically construct event handlers at run time. At this line an exception is thrown with the following message:

```
System.MissingMethodException: 'No parameterless constructor defined for this object.'
```

Which is logical, because in `OrderCreatedEventHandler` there is only one constructor with the repository injected. My question is: Is it possible to inject that repository in my dynamicly constructed handler? If not what could be a solution or workaround for my issue?

Additional info:

As IoC framework I use Autofac, and I configure it in `Startup.cs` where the domain events are also initialized:

```
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMokaKukaTrackerDbContext(CurrentEnvironment, Configuration);
        services.RegisterIdentityFramework();
        services.AddAndConfigureMvc(CurrentEnvironment);

        var autofacServiceProvider = new AutofacServiceProvider(CreateIoCContainer(services));
        DomainEvents.Init();

        return autofacServiceProvider;
    }

    private static IContainer CreateIoCContainer(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.Populate(services);
        builder.RegisterModule(new AutofacInjectorBootstrapperModule());

        return builder.Build();
    }
```

If you need any more info/code about my issue, let me know then I include them as soon as possible. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Pass the `IContainer` instance to the `DomainEvents.Init()`  then use that container to create handler instances

Comment: This is just a thought, but maybe you could just register all of your event handlers and their dependencies in autofac and resolve using autofac container instead of using Activator. Autofac is capable of picking up the right Constructor automatically. Autofac is powerful.

Comment: First and foremost, you shouldn't use static classes like that at all, its an anti-pattern. Just create it as regular class (with an interface) and have it injected into your Context. Your current approach is heavily problematic if you want to use scoped or transient services which are disposable (which DbContext is, since its default lifetime is scoped). Last but not least, `DomainEventDispatcher` shouldn't depend on EntityFramework, its a violation of concerns to mix and tightly couple it like that

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu and bart-256 Thanks for the comments, could be an workaround for the issue! But according to Tseng answer, the whole implementation is heavily problematic.

Comment: It is not *heavily problematic*, you just need to not use static/global variables; do some refactoring and it should be fine.

Comment: @Tseng Thanks a lot for your comment! I agree with you, I like your points! What do you think, what would be an another approach for using scoped dependencies and only commit the changes at the end of the transaction? Thank in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I decided to place my final solution for the problem as @Devesh Tipe requested it. The approved solution solved my issue, but I have done several refactoring in my code base in order to handle domain events in a more elegant way. With the following solution, we are able to create domain handlers with dependencies which are resolved in runtime via Autofac dependency framework. Let's dive into the code, including the whole solution:

First of all I have a marker interface for domain events:

```
public interface IDomainEvent
{
}
```

Then I have one interface for the domain handlers:

```
public interface IHandler<in T> where T : IDomainEvent
{
    void Handle(T domainEvent);
}
```

Furthermore I have an `EventDispatcher` which is responsible to dispatch/handle one event:

```
public class EventDispatcher : IEventDispatcher
{
    private readonly ILifetimeScope _lifetimeScope;

    public EventDispatcher(ILifetimeScope lifetimeScope)
    {
        _lifetimeScope = lifetimeScope;
    }

    public void Dispatch<TEvent>(TEvent eventToDispatch) where TEvent : IDomainEvent
    {
        foreach (dynamic handler in GetHandlers(eventToDispatch))
        {
            handler.Handle((dynamic)eventToDispatch);
        }
    }

    private IEnumerable GetHandlers<TEvent>(TEvent eventToDispatch) where TEvent : IDomainEvent
    {
        return (IEnumerable) _lifetimeScope.Resolve(
            typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(
                typeof(IHandler<>).MakeGenericType(eventToDispatch.GetType())));
    }
}
```

As you can see, here the corresponding handlers with their resolved dependencies are retrieved and invoked. This dispatcher is used in an executor class, like:

```
public class DomainEventHandlingsExecutor : IDomainEventHandlingsExecutor
{
    private readonly IEventDispatcher _domainEventDispatcher;

    public DomainEventHandlingsExecutor(IEventDispatcher domainEventDispatcher)
    {
        _domainEventDispatcher = domainEventDispatcher;
    }

    public void Execute(IEnumerable<IEntity> domainEventEntities)
    {
        foreach (var entity in domainEventEntities)
        {
            var events = entity.Events.ToArray();
            entity.Events.Clear();

            foreach (var @event in events)
            {
                _domainEventDispatcher.Dispatch(@event);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which is injected to my db context:

```
    public MokaKukaTrackerDbContext(DbContextOptions<MokaKukaTrackerDbContext> options, IDomainEventHandlingsExecutor domainEventHandlingsExecutor) : base(options)
    {
        _domainEventHandlingsExecutor = domainEventHandlingsExecutor;
    }

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        var numberOfChanges = base.SaveChanges();

        _domainEventHandlingsExecutor.Execute(GetDomainEventEntities());

        return numberOfChanges;
    }

    private IEnumerable<IEntity> GetDomainEventEntities()
    {
        return ChangeTracker.Entries<IEntity>()
            .Select(po => po.Entity)
            .Where(po => po.Events.Any())
            .ToArray();
    }
```

Last but not least I made and `AutofacModule` where I register all the handlers and logics relating to domain events handling:

```
public class AutofacEventHandlingBootstrapperModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType<EventDispatcher>().As<IEventDispatcher>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        builder.RegisterType<DomainEventHandlingsExecutor>().As<IDomainEventHandlingsExecutor>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        RegisterEventHandlersFromDomainModel(builder);
    }

    private static void RegisterEventHandlersFromDomainModel(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        var domainModelExecutingAssembly = new DomainModelExecutingAssemblyGetter().Get();

        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(domainModelExecutingAssembly)
            .Where(t => t.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i.IsClosedTypeOf(typeof(IHandler<>))))
            .AsImplementedInterfaces()
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    }
}
```

Which of course has to be registered in the `Startup.cs`:

```
   public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMokaKukaTrackerDbContext(CurrentEnvironment, Configuration);

        return new AutofacServiceProvider(CreateIoCContainer(services));
    }

    private static IContainer CreateIoCContainer(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.Populate(services);
        builder.RegisterModule(new AutofacInjectorBootstrapperModule());
        builder.RegisterModule(new AutofacEventHandlingBootstrapperModule());

        return builder.Build();
    }
```

That's it, I hope it helps someone!

Comment: sure I can! I am now in abroad, but monday I got back then I will include it here ;)

Comment: I use above solution but in last state that ApplicationUserRepository used to update data I got this error:
Cannot access a disposed object. A common cause of this error is disposing a context that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling Dispose() on the context, or wrapping the context in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.
Object name: 'AppIdentityDbContext'.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to use the Dependency Injection Container to create instances of objects that have dependencies. For this you need to pass the `IContainer` down to the `DomainEvents` instance, i.e. passing as an argument to the `DomainEvents.Init()` method call.

```
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMokaKukaTrackerDbContext(CurrentEnvironment, Configuration);
        services.RegisterIdentityFramework();
        services.AddAndConfigureMvc(CurrentEnvironment);

        var container = CreateIoCContainer(services);
        var autofacServiceProvider = new AutofacServiceProvider(container);
        DomainEvents.Init(container);

        return autofacServiceProvider;
    }
```

Then, the `DomainEvents` class should store a reference to the `container` and use it in the `Dispatch` method.

*Note 1:* I don't have a lot of experience with C# so I'm not sure if `IContainer` or `IServiceProvider` should be injected into `DomainEvents`

*Note 2:* As @TSeng said in the comments, try to not use static methods; refactor to use instances of classes instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I appreaciate your help! So I should pass the `Icontainer` into my `DomainEvents` class, then there construct the event handlers, right? How and why should I use the `container` in `Dispatch` method?

Comment: @mirind4 as I mentioned, I don't have experience with C#, but in other OOP languages (i.e. PHP) the container can be used to instantiate simple or complex objects (that have a lot of nested dependencies). I don't know *how exactly* you call the *container* to create an instance of a specific type.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I gonna dive into the code and check what I can can come up with ;)

Comment: By all means! :)

Comment: I successfully solved it. Well, I have done several refactoring, but the solution is indeed to inject the container into my domain event initializer class and resolve the dependencies there. To be exact, I had to inject `ILifetimeScope` instead of `IContainer` because it is the way how it should be done with Autofac IoC framework. I accept you answey anyway, thanks for you help! Best wishes ;)